# Start counting after scroll on specific element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I create a website and add a counter to my codes.

```js
$(function() {
    function count($this){
        var current = parseInt($this.html(), 10);
        $this.html(++current);
        if(current !== $this.data('count')){
            setTimeout(function(){count($this)}, 50);
        }
    }        
  $(".c-section4").each(function() {
      $(this).data('count', parseInt($(this).html(), 10));
      $(this).html('0');
      count($(this));
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<div class="section4">
<div class="section4-bg"></div>

<div class="counter-section">
<span class="c-section4">152 </span>
<h3> کارکنان ما </h3>
</div>

<div class="counter-section">
<span class="c-section4">152 </span>
<h3> کارکنان ما </h3>
</div>

<div class="counter-section">
<span class="c-section4">152 </span>
<h3> کارکنان ما </h3>
</div>

</div>
```

Now i have a problem, i want to counter start when i scroll to this element

[Demo](http://persian-gamers.ir/wood/)

Sorry for my bad english

Comment: _i want to counter start when i scroll to this element_... Good but I can't see any attempt to use scroll !!

Comment: please see my demo, if you look at the counter in demo , you can see counter start counting when site was loading , but i want just start counting when i scroll to the element (i want to see counting from 0 to my number)

Comment: so you want counter should start when you scroll the page

Comment: @AlirezaBehnamnik can you tell me your exact requirement?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can handle the window `scroll` event and use the function given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/488073/1009922) by [Scott Dowding](https://stackoverflow.com/users/41669/scott-dowding) to determine if the element has been scrolled into view. An `isCounting` flag can be set on each element to prevent counting several times simultaneously.

In the following code snippet, the counting is performed only while the element is visible.

```js
$(function () {
    function isScrolledIntoView($elem) {
        var docViewTop = $(window).scrollTop();
        var docViewBottom = docViewTop + $(window).height();
        var elemTop = $elem.offset().top;
        var elemBottom = elemTop + $elem.height();
        return ((elemBottom <= docViewBottom) && (elemTop >= docViewTop));
    }

    function count($this) {
        var current = parseInt($this.html(), 10);
        if (isScrolledIntoView($this) && !$this.data("isCounting") && current < $this.data('count')) {
            $this.html(++current);
            $this.data("isCounting", true);
            setTimeout(function () {
                $this.data("isCounting", false);
                count($this);
            }, 50);
        }
    }

    $(".c-section4").each(function () {
        $(this).data('count', parseInt($(this).html(), 10));
        $(this).html('0');
        $(this).data("isCounting", false);
    });

    function startCount() {
        $(".c-section4").each(function () {
            count($(this));
        });
    };

    $(window).scroll(function () {
        startCount();
    });

    startCount();
});
```

```css
.tallDiv 
{
   height: 800px;
   background-color: silver;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>

<div class="section4">
  <div class="section4-bg"></div>
  <div class="tallDiv">Scroll down to test</div>
  <div class="counter-section">
    <span class="c-section4">152 </span>
    <h3> کارکنان ما </h3>
  </div>
  <div class="counter-section">
    <span class="c-section4">152 </span>
    <h3> کارکنان ما </h3>
  </div>
  <div class="counter-section">
    <span class="c-section4">152 </span>
    <h3> کارکنان ما </h3>
  </div>
  <div class="tallDiv"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: If I take one **15**, one **125** and one **5652** what is happen here ?
It is going to take like a unlimited time. How we can solved it ? 
I already try to reduce  by the time to 5s [LIVE_LINK](https://jsfiddle.net/ashikjs/4xoqrvx7/)

Comment: Hello. How can I speed up this animation? What parameter defines how long this effect should continue?

Comment: @AndriiPryimak - In `function count($this) { ... }`, the timeout is set to 50 ms. You can speed up the animation by decreasing that timeout. The animation keeps going until it reaches the value set in the `span` elements (152 in the markup shown above); you can also change that value.

Answer (score 3):

You need to give the target element and id, then get its postition from top `var pos = document.getElementById('targetId').scrollHeight - element.clientHeight;` and compare it to the scrolled height `window.pageYOffset`.

If widow offset is greater than the pos, you can start the counter. You should hook the comparison to the `window.onscroll` event.

Also you should memorize in a variable if you started the counter for an element already to avoid starting it twice.

Answer (score 3):

[Live Link](https://jsfiddle.net/ashikjs/01834rs6/)

You can use this Plugin for it. Source [LINK](http://demo.tinywall.net/numscroller/)

```
<span class='numscroller numscroller-big-bottom' data-slno='1' data-min='0'
 data-max='82' data-delay='19' data-increment="2">0</span>
```

**NB:** `data-max='**'`give your max-number and `data-delay='**'` select a time for countdown running and select  increment `data-increment="**"` .

```js
/**
* jQuery scroroller Plugin 1.0
*
* http://www.tinywall.net/
* 
* Developers: Arun David, Boobalan
* Copyright (c) 2014 
*/
(function($){
    $(window).on("load",function(){
        $(document).scrollzipInit();
        $(document).rollerInit();
    });
    $(window).on("load scroll resize", function(){
        $('.numscroller').scrollzip({
            showFunction    :   function() {
                                    numberRoller($(this).attr('data-slno'));
                                },
            wholeVisible    :     false,
        });
    });
    $.fn.scrollzipInit=function(){
        $('body').prepend("<div style='position:fixed;top:0px;left:0px;width:0;height:0;' id='scrollzipPoint'></div>" );
    };
    $.fn.rollerInit=function(){
        var i=0;
        $('.numscroller').each(function() {
            i++;
           $(this).attr('data-slno',i); 
           $(this).addClass("roller-title-number-"+i);
        });        
    };
    $.fn.scrollzip = function(options){
        var settings = $.extend({
            showFunction    : null,
            hideFunction    : null,
            showShift       : 0,
            wholeVisible    : false,
            hideShift       : 0,
        }, options);
        return this.each(function(i,obj){
            $(this).addClass('scrollzip');
            if ( $.isFunction( settings.showFunction ) ){
                if(
                    !$(this).hasClass('isShown')&&
                    ($(window).outerHeight()+$('#scrollzipPoint').offset().top-settings.showShift)>($(this).offset().top+((settings.wholeVisible)?$(this).outerHeight():0))&&
                    ($('#scrollzipPoint').offset().top+((settings.wholeVisible)?$(this).outerHeight():0))<($(this).outerHeight()+$(this).offset().top-settings.showShift)
                ){
                    $(this).addClass('isShown');
                    settings.showFunction.call( this );
                }
            }
            if ( $.isFunction( settings.hideFunction ) ){
                if(
                    $(this).hasClass('isShown')&&
                    (($(window).outerHeight()+$('#scrollzipPoint').offset().top-settings.hideShift)<($(this).offset().top+((settings.wholeVisible)?$(this).outerHeight():0))||
                    ($('#scrollzipPoint').offset().top+((settings.wholeVisible)?$(this).outerHeight():0))>($(this).outerHeight()+$(this).offset().top-settings.hideShift))
                ){
                    $(this).removeClass('isShown');
                    settings.hideFunction.call( this );
                }
            }
            return this;
        });
    };
    function numberRoller(slno){
            var min=$('.roller-title-number-'+slno).attr('data-min');
            var max=$('.roller-title-number-'+slno).attr('data-max');
            var timediff=$('.roller-title-number-'+slno).attr('data-delay');
            var increment=$('.roller-title-number-'+slno).attr('data-increment');
            var numdiff=max-min;
            var timeout=(timediff*1000)/numdiff;
            //if(numinc<10){
                //increment=Math.floor((timediff*1000)/10);
            //}//alert(increment);
            numberRoll(slno,min,max,increment,timeout);
            
    }
    function numberRoll(slno,min,max,increment,timeout){//alert(slno+"="+min+"="+max+"="+increment+"="+timeout);
        if(min<=max){
            $('.roller-title-number-'+slno).html(min);
            min=parseInt(min)+parseInt(increment);
            setTimeout(function(){numberRoll(eval(slno),eval(min),eval(max),eval(increment),eval(timeout))},timeout);
        }else{
            $('.roller-title-number-'+slno).html(max);
        }
    }
})(jQuery);
```

```css
.nm {
 height: 400px;
 background: #f5f5f5;
 display: block;
}
.nm_1 {
 background-color: #632525;
}
.nm_2 {
 background-color: grad;
}
.nm_3 {
 background-color: gray;
}
.nm_4 {
 background-color: green;
}
.nm_5 {
 background-color: georgian;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section class="nm nm_1">
</section>
<section class="nm nm_2">
</section>
<section class="nm nm_3">
</section>
<section class="nm nm_4">
 
 <div>
  <span class='numscroller numscroller-big-bottom' data-slno='1' data-min='0' data-max='192' data-delay='19' data-increment="2">0</span>
  <h3> کارکنان ما </h3>
 </div>
 <div>
  <span class='numscroller numscroller-big-bottom' data-slno='1' data-min='0' data-max='282' data-delay='19' data-increment="2">0</span>
  <h3> کارکنان ما </h3>
 </div>
 <div>
  <span class='numscroller numscroller-big-bottom' data-slno='1' data-min='0' data-max='82' data-delay='19' data-increment="2">0</span>
  <h3> کارکنان ما </h3>
 </div>
  
  
 
</section>
<section class="nm nm_4">
</section>
<section class="nm nm_5">
</section>
```

Answer (score 3):

Get the scroll Height and compare with the height of the start div(count start div) put a condition

```js
$(function() {
  var pos = document.getElementById('targetId').scrollHeight;
  console.log(pos);
  
  if(pos>="75"){
  
    function count($this){
        var current = parseInt($this.html(), 10);
        $this.html(++current);
        if(current !== $this.data('count')){
            setTimeout(function(){count($this)}, 50);
        }
    }        
  $(".c-section4").each(function() {
      $(this).data('count', parseInt($(this).html(), 10));
      $(this).html('0');
      count($(this));
  });
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>



<div class="counter-section" id="targetId">
<span class="c-section4">152 </span>
<h3> کارکنان ما </h3>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's my solution which supports floats and a configurable animation duration. It will only animate the count one time - as soon the element appears in the viewport of the specified container.

```js
const initAnimatedCounts = () => {
  const ease = (n) => {
    // https://github.com/component/ease/blob/master/index.js
    return --n * n * n + 1;
  };
  const observer = new IntersectionObserver((entries) => {
    entries.forEach((entry) => {
      if (entry.isIntersecting) {
        // Once this element is in view and starts animating, remove the observer,
        // because it should only animate once per page load.
        observer.unobserve(entry.target);
        const countToString = entry.target.getAttribute('data-countTo');
        const countTo = parseFloat(countToString);
        const duration = parseFloat(entry.target.getAttribute('data-animateDuration'));
        const countToParts = countToString.split('.');
        const precision = countToParts.length === 2 ? countToParts[1].length : 0;
        const startTime = performance.now();
        const step = (currentTime) => {
          const progress = Math.min(ease((currentTime  - startTime) / duration), 1);
          entry.target.textContent = (progress * countTo).toFixed(precision);
          if (progress < 1) {
            animationFrame = window.requestAnimationFrame(step);
          } else {
            window.cancelAnimationFrame(animationFrame);
          }
        };
        let animationFrame = window.requestAnimationFrame(step);
      }
    });
  });
  document.querySelectorAll('[data-animateDuration]').forEach((target) => {
    target.setAttribute('data-countTo', target.textContent);
    target.textContent = '0';
    observer.observe(target);
  });
};
initAnimatedCounts();
```

```css
div {
  font-size: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 30px 0;
}
div > span {
  color: #003d82;
}
div.scrollpad {
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: #eee;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span>$<span data-animateDuration="1000">987.45</span></span> was spent on
  about <span><span data-animateDuration="1000">5.8</span>M</span> things.
</div>
<div class="scrollpad">keep scrolling</div>
<div>
  There are <span><span data-animateDuration="1000">878</span>K</span> people involved.
  <br/>
  And <span><span data-animateDuration="1000">54</span></span> cakes.
</div>
<div class="scrollpad">keep scrolling</div>
<div>
  Additionally, <span>$<span data-animateDuration="3000">300</span>B</span> went to waste.
  <br/>
  Because <span>$<span data-animateDuration="2000">54</span></span> was spent on each cake.
</div>
<div class="scrollpad">keep scrolling</div>
<div>
  Lastly, <span><span data-animateDuration="4000">3.5334583</span>T</span> ants said hello.
  <br/>
  But <span><span data-animateDuration="2000">4</span></span> of them said goodbye.
</div>
```